# Android Maps Missing

Tags: android, maps

I'm trying to use Android maps in Android. I have followed [this tutorial here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2):, and done the following:

- Downloaded all packages in the Android SDK
- Added `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>` to the android manifest.

I haven't yet got a key, but I feel like I should at least be able to compile the code. I'm getting the following import errors. These imports don't exist:

```
 import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
 import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
 import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
 import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
 import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;
```

Does anyone know why Google maps isn't added to my project?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer: I was compiling for an android project and not a google sdk target. So strange.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on what the answer is, or indeed what the question was.  Are the lines shown the error message, or something that appears before another message reporting a link  failure?